# Notification When Screen is Flashing VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like a notification to be triggered when part the screen starts to flash.  This notification can be a msgbox for now, but I will eventually evolve it into an audible sound.

The purpose of this is we have a dashboard that displays various cells throughout the company.  When a cell needs assistance, its spot on the dashboard starts to flash.  The cells are displayed in horizontally stackedboxes like this;

---

Cell 1

---

Cell 2

---

Cell 3

---

Ect...

---

I would like to build an application that scans the screen, lets say every second, and gets each cells pixel intensity.

The notification will be triggered if/when the cells pixel intensity changes each scan for three consecutive scans in a row (ie. the cell must be flashing).

I am hoping that you guys can help me find a way to scan the screen an return a regions average pixel intensity to which I can then replicate and do the comparison to find out if it is flashing.

Thank you in advance, I am using VB.Net.

Comment: Since you described the whole project, it's hard to know what type of help you are looking for exactly... Maybe you should start by finding how to get a screen capture? Or maybe just start by trying to execute a thread? The best way would be to update the dashboard to make sound.

Comment: why not just modify the dashboard program instead?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish what I was asking by using this:

```
 Private Sub AvgColors(ByVal InBitmap As Bitmap)
        Dim btPixels(InBitmap.Height * InBitmap.Width * 3 - 1) As Byte
        Dim hPixels As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(btPixels, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        Dim bmp24Bpp As New Bitmap(InBitmap.Width, InBitmap.Height, InBitmap.Width * 3,
          Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, hPixels.AddrOfPinnedObject)

        Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp24Bpp)
            gr.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(InBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0,
              bmp24Bpp.Width, bmp24Bpp.Height))
        End Using

        Dim sumRed As Int32
        Dim sumGreen As Int32
        Dim sumBlue As Int32

        For i = 0 To btPixels.Length - 1 Step 3
            sumRed += btPixels(i)
            sumGreen += btPixels(i + 1)
            sumBlue += btPixels(i + 2)
        Next
        hPixels.Free()
        Dim avgRed As Byte = CByte(sumRed / (btPixels.Length / 3))
        Dim avgGreen As Byte = CByte(sumGreen / (btPixels.Length / 3))
        Dim avgBlue As Byte = CByte(sumBlue / (btPixels.Length / 3))


        MsgBox(avgRed & vbCrLf & avgGreen & vbCrLf & avgBlue)
    End Sub

    Private Function Screenshot() As Bitmap
        Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b)
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
            g.Save()
        End Using

        Return b
    End Function
```

and from here I can just adjust the range of bitmap to what I need, add a timer to tick every second, and keep a variable to compare average RGB's to.

Most of the code found from here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?776021-RESOLVED-Getting-Average-RGB-Color-Value-of-Entire-Screen